# req.body (request body) gives an empty value with ajax submitting form in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, ejs

I am new to nodejs and i am facing a  issue in nodjs. i am trying to access the form value in controller via `req.body`.

**CONTROLLER:**

```
exports.createNavigation = (req, res, next) =>{
console.log(req.body);// this is always blank
}
```

**AJAX:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "<%- pathHelper.baseUrl('admin/navigation/create') %>",
  type: "POST",
  //data: {'name': 'kashif'}, //this is working and i get name in controller
  data: new FormData($("#create-form")[0]), //trying to get this in controller
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  dataType: "json",
  beforeSend: function() {
    $("#createBtn").attr("disabled", true);
    $(".message_box")
      .html("")
      .removeClass("alert-success")
      .addClass("hide alert-danger");
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
    $("#createBtn").attr("disabled", false);
    var msg = formatErrorMessage(jqXHR, exception);
    $(".message_box")
      .html(msg)
      .removeClass("hide");
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $("#createBtn").attr("disabled", false);
    $(".message_box")
      .html(data.msg)
      .removeClass("hide alert-danger")
      .addClass("alert-success");
  }
});
```

**FORM:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="create-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label"
      >Name <i class="has-error">*</i></label
    >
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        name="name"
        placeholder="Name"
        value=""
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Server/app.js**

```
    var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000 ;

//imports
const http =  require('http');
const path =  require('path');
const rootDir = require('./util/path').rootDir;
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser =  require('body-parser');
const admnRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
const errorController = require('./controllers/admin/errorController');
const mongoConnect = require('./util/database').mongoConnect;
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
const app = express();
const store = new MongoDBStore({
    uri: '****',
    collection: 'sessions'
});
//template engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

//utils and heplers
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended': false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(rootDir, 'public')));
app.use(session({
    secret:'my sercret',
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized:false,
    store:store,
}));
//routes
app.use('/admin', admnRoutes);
app.get('/', errorController.login);
app.use(errorController.page404);

//create table and run server
mongoConnect(() => {
    app.listen(PORT);
})
```

I am trying to post the form using ajax and trying to get the value in controller .  If i am using `data: {'name': 'kashif'}`,  then I am able to access name in `console.log` but unable to access formdata

Comment: can you add the server.js code also.

Comment: @RahulSharma,  i have added the server.js code

Comment: @kashif Try using `data : $('#create-form').serialize();` instead of `new FormData($("#create-form")[0])`.

Comment: @ambianBeing, it work with serialize but why is the issue with mutipart in nodejs and formdata ??

Comment: @kashif The issue is not sending `multipart/form-data` if at all you're sending, it is understanding/parsing at the express end. U'll need something like **multer** to do that. Since u'dont have any file input the form simply don't do this `new FormData($("#create-form")[0])` that is sending it as formdata.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, There are two ways.

1. Easiest way, You are trying to send multipart/form-data. You can serialize the form data. Example,

```
var $form = $("#create-form");

$.ajax({
  url: "<%- pathHelper.baseUrl('admin/navigation/create') %>",
  type: "POST",
  //data: {'name': 'kashif'}, //this is working and i get name in controller
  data: $form.serialize(), // serialize will help you
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  dataType: "json",
  beforeSend: function() {
    $("#createBtn").attr("disabled", true);
    $(".message_box")
      .html("")
      .removeClass("alert-success")
      .addClass("hide alert-danger");
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
    $("#createBtn").attr("disabled", false);
    var msg = formatErrorMessage(jqXHR, exception);
    $(".message_box")
      .html(msg)
      .removeClass("hide");
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $("#createBtn").attr("disabled", false);
    $(".message_box")
      .html(data.msg)
      .removeClass("hide alert-danger")
      .addClass("alert-success");
  }
});
```

2. You can use **multer** npm package that allows you to send multipart/form-data.